# Options for login

Tags: login, ux-field

I'm designing login screen for a music app like gaana, wynk.
I have two options

- Login with google and facebook
- Getting Username and password

Which is better?

Comment: Better is using both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i often discussed the same question with my team..its quit **easy to use the login using social**.. its popular to **login in a single tap, its very good UX**. **but** think about some situation , **Some user love to make secrete about there privacy, they don't even like to share even there name too.** 
Think about the situation they want to listen music but did not want to share their personal detail. and Facebook login / google login API will explore your name detail and rest,but they dint want it..
i often see in stack-overflow or in Stack exchange people are with there fake name instead of original name.

I think, if you will give both option, then it will be very good for the user

Answer (score 0):

Surely it will be easier for the user to login with Google or Facebook. However, not always the development team is keen of implementing this feature as sometimes there might be some issues with user data sync.

The latest UX trends are also suggesting the login with Social accounts.